# Google artifact registry list_tags in python - contains invalid argument

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-artifact-registry

I'm a code newbie so please be kind :) I've got my google credentials set and I've checked the documentation for the python library for artifact registry (v1), but clearly doing something daft, as I'm receiving this response back - `google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Request contains an invalid argument.`

Here's my code:

```
from google.cloud import artifactregistry_v1

# Using Application Default Credentails is easiest
# export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/key.json
client = artifactregistry_v1.ArtifactRegistryClient()

# Best obtained from the environment
project = "**REDACTED**" 
location = "europe-west2"
repository = "test"

parent = f"projects/{project}/locations/{location}/repositories/{repository}"

request = artifactregistry_v1.ListTagsRequest(parent=parent)

page_result = client.list_tags(request=request)

for response in page_result:
    print(response)
```

Here's the official docs, I can't work out what I've done wrong: https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/artifactregistry/latest/google.cloud.artifactregistry_v1.services.artifact_registry.ArtifactRegistryClient#google_cloud_artifactregistry_v1_services_artifact_registry_ArtifactRegistryClient_list_tags

**EDIT**

Just seen on the Google docs for the Class `ListTagsRequest` ([here](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/artifactregistry/latest/google.cloud.artifactregistry_v1.types.ListTagsRequest)) it says `parent` expects a string (which is what i've done), but noticed in PyCharm it's highlighted and telling me `expected type 'Dict', and got 'str' instead`....

Comment: I tested your program and I have exactly the same error and behavior. The doc is not clear about the parent value, but I used it in the same way than listFiles. It works for ListFiles but not for ListTags. The error is : `<_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
 status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
 details = "Request contains an invalid argument."
 debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv6:{IP VALUE} {created_time:"2022-12-21T12:17:02.298535+01:00", grpc_status:3, grpc_message:"Request contains an invalid argument."}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to find the correct code :

```py
from google.cloud import artifactregistry_v1


def get_package_tags_from_artifact_registry():
    # Using Application Default Credentails is easiest
    # export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/key.json
    client = artifactregistry_v1.ArtifactRegistryClient()

    # Best obtained from the environment
    project = "{project_id}"
    location = "{location}"
    repository = "{repository}"
    package_name = "{package_name}"

    parent = f"projects/{project}/locations/{location}/repositories/{repository}/packages/{package_name}"

    request = artifactregistry_v1.ListTagsRequest(
        parent=parent
    )

    page_result = client.list_tags(
        request=request
    )

    for response in page_result:
        print(response)

    return page_result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = get_package_tags_from_artifact_registry()
```

I checked from this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.repositories.packages.tags/list) and tested with a parent path including the `package` name.

Comment: I am running into a similar issue. It's very disappointing that the errors are so opaque and they seemed to have not improved in the past year.